How to get shard gitlab-runner ip?
I tried to deploy a project on the shared gitlab-runner and created the following yaml file:
  image: gradle:8.8.0-jdk17

  stages:
    - build
    - deploy

  before_script:
    - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=$(pwd)/.gradle

  build:
    stage: build
    script:
      - gradle clean build
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - build/libs/*.jar


  deploy:
    stage: deploy
    script:
      - nohup java -jar build/libs/*.jar &
    only:
      - main

After pushing I received the success message in the pipeline logs.
In the case when I deployed the project on the runner that was registered on my AWS instance I was able to get access to my API, now I don't understand how to get the (shared) runner IP to start using my project. I don't see any ip's or something similar. Could anyone help me understand the shared runners deploying logic?
